# Jusqu'à outrance ou jusqu'à l'outrance

Tags: expressions

J'ai lu récemment un article utilisant l'expression *jusqu'à l'outrance*. Or j'ai l'habitude d'entendre ou d'utiliser *jusqu'à outrance*.

Le [wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_outrance) mentionne *à outrance* mais pas de *à l'outrance*. Sur internet on retrouve des articles de grands journaux utilisant *à l'outrance* ([exemple](http://www.liberation.fr/politiques/2010/11/24/sarkozy-confidences-jusqu-a-l-outrance_695899)).

Bref, y a-t-il une formulation plus correcte que l'autre ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La locution **[à outrance](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/outrance)** (voir C.) existe effectivement, et pourrait donc donner *jusqu'à outrance*, sans être a priori choquante.

C'est cependant une répétition (sans grande gravité, je le concède) dans la mesure où le sens même de la locution contient déjà l'idée de *jusqu'à*, contracté dans son *à* initial.

L'expression *jusqu'à l'outrance*, plus longue et ayant peut-être une connotation légèrement plus littéraire, a le même sens mais évite cette répétition.

On peut éventuellement faire l'analogie avec une autre expression ayant la même structure mais plus utilisée : *à mort* / *jusqu'à la mort* ont le même sens, mais *jusqu'à mort* serait redondant.